# Does this sum involving the central binomial coefficient have a closed form expression?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

Since Lehmer we know that
$$
\sum_{n\geq1} \binom{2n}{n}^{-1} = \frac{2\pi\sqrt3}{27} + \frac43,
$$
which is due to the identity
$$
\sum_{n\geq1} x^n \binom{2n}{n}^{-1} = \int_0^1 \frac{x(1-t)}{(1-xt(1-t))^2} dt.
$$
Substituting different values of $x$ above gives a variety of remarkable formulae.

However, I have not found similar expressions for any $\sum_{n\geq1} \binom{2n}{n}^{-k}$ with $k>1$. In particular, I am interested in $\sum_{n\geq1} \binom{2n}{n}^{-2}$. Unfortunately I cannot get a better ''closed form'' expression for this sum than the hypergeometric series $\frac14{}_3F_2(1,2,2;\frac32,\frac32;\frac{1}{16})$.

> Does a closed form expression exist for $\sum_{n\geq1}
> > \binom{2n}{n}^{-2}$?

Comment: Seems related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2833496/convergence-of-sum-of-reciprocals-of-binomial-coefficients

Comment: @Sil Yes, it does. Thank you.

Comment: @Sil: wow, I did not remember posting the same qeustion 2 years ago. Strange!